# Instabilities in constant current sources at low load impedances

Tags: current, stability, source

I want to turn my constant voltage source into a constant current, voltage controlled. For this, I used the following circuit.
[image: CONSTANT VOLTAGE/CONSTANT CURRENT SOURCE]

If the ERV error signal is connected to the UCT, the assembly functions as a constant voltage source
VOUT = V4 * (R6 + R12) / R12. It works perfectly.
If the ERV error signal is connected to the output of the VIU isolating current-voltage converter made with U2, U3, U4 the assembly works as a constant current source VIU = V4, where VIU = 50 * R17 * IS. The U4 follower has been introduced for the range of small supplied currents, when R17 has high values.
The constant current source works well ONLY IF THE LOAD RESISTANCE HAS A MINIMUM VALUE, provided in my circuit by R13. For example, for the current range of + -10mA, when R17 = 20, if R25 = 0 and R13> = 300, the current source works correctly, the current IS (t) being represented in the next figure.
[image: IS(t) for R13>=300]

If R25 = 0 and R13 = 150, IS (t) has the oscillations below, represented global and in detail.
[image: IS(t) for R13=150; global image]

[image: IS(t) for R13=150; detail]

MY QUESTION IS: WHY DO THESE OSCILLATIONS APPEAR AND HOW CAN I AVOID THEM SO THAT THE SOURCE CAN WORK WITHOUT OSCILLATIONS AND FOR R13 <300? Thank you!!

Comment: The schematic is unreadable. Could you please upload a bigger version of it?

Comment: All your images please (ditto)

Comment: If you've built your own current source onto an existing voltage source, then there's every possibility that the added things have made it go unstable, for certain values of load. Unfortunately your schematic is not only unreadable, but you don't indicate what you think is controlling what. We need a walk-through of what you think are the principles of operation - where the current is sensed, what it controls, and what you think are the stability issues with that loop.

Comment: My initial impression is that this is a very complex loop that presents potential opportunities for oscillation as you change the current and load impedance. Have you attempted to measure the phase margin (not just oscillate/non oscillate)? Also, a square wave might be better for testing.

Comment: You do not seem to have any series current sensing resistors and too many unnecessary voltage feedback loops.  Can you define any load regulation specs or voltage or current regulation specs? stimulus BW and  Noise specs?  Yet you have a nice 50 kHz oscillator

Comment: @ Tony Stewart EE75: The current sensing resistor is R17. In this configuration, we obtain +-170V as constant voltage source and +-10mA as constant current source.

Comment: You haven't shown where ERV connects - this is vital.

Answer (score 3):

I've had to deal with the exact same problem recently: A power supply that went unstable in constant current mode when the load resistance was too low. This is caused by the circuit's loop gain increasing when the load resistance decreases: The lower the resistance, the higher the current swing for a given output voltage swing. This increases the circuit's unity-gain frequency and in turn reduces its phase margin until it oscillates.

The solution is to lower the gain of the feedback loop. Your circuit seems to employ dominant-pole compensation via C1. If you increase the value of this capacitor, the overall circuit's gain at high frequencies decreases. This improves stability.

You should also remove C7 and R21 as additional low-passes (poles) in the feedback loop lead to instability. C6 also introduces an unnecessary pole; decrease its value as much as you can (i.e. to 10pF). If the circuit gets too slow when you do this, decrease the value of R18.

In general, when you have a feedback loop that uses dominant-pole compensation, never add additional lowpasses in that feedback loop. (Unless these lowpasses only filter out frequencies way above the circuit's unity-gain frequency.) Doing so will lead to instability and oscillations due to the added phase lag.

You should always verify such a circuit's unity-gain frequency and phase margin via AC simulations at various loading conditions, as Spehro Pefhany mentioned in the comments.